# Notifications don't show up until I wake the phone

Tags: notifications, standby, 7.0-nougat, nexus-5x

I have identical problem on two Nexus 5x phones.
In last few weeks I've noticed that I don't receive any notification(Gmail, calendar, sms...) when phone is in "sleep mode" but when I wake it up (with power button, shake etc) the notifications show up immediately.

**1. I thought there is something wrong with the notifications settings**

- Settings->notifications->configuration:
- Pulse notification light: "ON"
- On the lock screen: "Show all notification content"

**2. I checked every settings of every app**

- everything is set correctly

**3. Battery saver** - "OFF"

- Settings->Battery->Battery saver

**4. Doze (battery optimization for apps)**

- Settings->Battery->(drop down menu)->Battery optimization
- Every app moved to "Not optimized"

*(updated)*

**5. Data Saver** - "OFF"

*(updated)*

**6. Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep** - "Always"

Settings->Wi-Fi->Gear icon->Keep Wi-Fi

---

and still...NOTHING :(

I have made a simple demonstration with Calendar event notification:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoCgA1rkq18

**Technical info:**

- **Phone:** LG Nexus 5x
- **OS:** Android 7.0 (Nougat)
- **App killers installed:** NO
- **Rooted:** NO
- **Custom ROM:** NO
- **Connection:** tried with every combination = Offline, WiFi, Mobile data, Wifi + data

Thx for help and sorry for my english :-)